# Trigger CI when a commit is pushed and a PR is approved?

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

I used to have a GitHub Actions workflow configured like this:

```
name: CI

on: [push, pull_request]
```

I was interested in switching my trigger to a PR approval instead, so I changed it to:

```
name: CI

on: [push, pull_request_review]
```

and in the job I added the following `if` element:

```
  myJob:
    name: Name of my job
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || github.event.review.state == 'approved'
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    container: ...
```

However, the push trigger keeps working but the PR approval trigger does not.

I've also tried to define my `on:` setting in a more specific way, like this:

```
on:
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]
  push:
```

But it doesn't do the trick. What else am I missing to make this work? I extracted all the above know-how from [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-a-workflow-when-a-pull-request-is-approved).

Comment: You have an `||` (`or`), and you need `&&` instead

Comment: what? the trigger needs to happen when push OR pr_review

Comment: Your title says AND. If you need the `or` check that your workflow file with the second approach with (pull_request_review: types: [submitted]) is on the default branch

Comment: man, think about it; if I put && there, it's not going to be triggered ever because it cannot happen that `github.event.review.state == 'approved'` when the event_name is `push`

Answer (score 1):

Argh, it was not a code issue, but a settings issue! If the repo is private, this has to be enabled: https://github.com/user/repo/settings/actions -> option **Run workflows from fork pull requests** (if the repository is under an organization, it has to be enabled first in the organization settings; after that, it can be enabled in the repository settings).